# I want to split an object and pass to my POJO setter

Tags: jquery, json, spring-data-jpa

I have a one POJO class which has a one-to-many relationship in Spring JPA. I am sending all data from jQuery converting it to JSON and I want to split my data according to my relationship but I am not able to that.

I have tried so many functions of but none worked for me.

```
@Entity
public class PassengerContact implements Serializable 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String pName;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String pEmail;
    @Column(nullable = false,length = 10)
    private String contact;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="fkPcid",referencedColumnName="id")
    private List<PassengerDetail> passengerdetail;
    //getter //setter

    // create an ObjectMapper instance.
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    // use the ObjectMapper to read the json string and create a tree
    JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(genreJson);
```

My object coming from jQuery looks like this:

```js
[{
  "pName": "nitish",
  "pEmail": "test@gmail.com",
  "contact": "8770277336"
}, {
  "passengerdetail": [{
    "seatNo": "32",
    "pname": "455",
    "age": 4,
    "gender": "Male"
  }, {
    "seatNo": "33",
    "pname": "rere",
    "age": 44,
    "gender": "Male"
  }]
}]
```

Comment: {
  "pName": "nitish",
  "pEmail": "test@gmail.com",
  "contact": "8770277336",
  "passengerdetail": [{
    "seatNo": "32",
    "pname": "455",
    "age": 4,
    "gender": "Male"
  }, {
    "seatNo": "33",
    "pname": "rere",
    "age": 44,
    "gender": "Male"
  }]
}